# Where are the file stored for conversion?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

If a developer uses the google driver SDK , specifically converting documents , does anyone know where the documents are stored i.e the location of the server. We are in the UK so we need to adhere to safe harbour protocols and wouldn't necessary would want to share our data with Google for various legal reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Google drive sdk to upload files to a users Google drive account there is no way for you to know where in the world the data is stored. This actually has nothing to do with the SDK and more to do with Google drive it self.

The [file.resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) does not contain any information about where the file is in the world.  Nor is there a way for you to set where the file is to reside when you upload it.

This information is only known by Google.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo. That helps clear one thing. I can also see that Google Cloud have / are planning to incorportate GDPR compliance into their Drive solutions https://cloud.google.com/security/gdpr/. Would you know if Google plans to use this data for advertising purposes. I know Google is an ad company but just wanted to make sure if it applies to conversion of documents or not . Thanks for the quick reply earlier.